# How do I tag someone in TF2

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm playing the new Halloween version but whenever I get tagged by someone who has been chased by the headless horsemen I'm left running for my life because I don't know how to tag someone else!

Comment: How do I get a melee weapon?

Comment: Melee weapons are the weapons in the third slot (e.g. Wrench, Bat, Shovel).

Answer (score 12):

You need to hit an enemy player with a melee weapon.

Note: The Horseless Headless Horsemann will only chase you for a certain distance before he gives up and goes after someone else.

Comment: How do I get a melee weapon?

Comment: @Madison You should have one by default. Cycle through your weapons (scroll the mouse wheel, or press the number buttons). Every class will always have one melee weapon.

Comment: All classes in TF2 all have primary, secondary, and melee weapons when they spawn.  It's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the general gist.

Comment: Engineer also has the Construction Toolkit and Destruction Toolkit.  Spy's primary *is* his melee and his Revolver is considered a secondary... but he has a Sapper, Cloaking Device, and Disguise Kit to make up for it.